# Unable to resolve AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-elasticsearch

Hi All i have downloaded the below code from AWS in order to index the data to my elasticsearch service but it has end up with error i am unable to build the code.

```
package com.Lambda.dynamodb;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.http.AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AmazonElasticsearchServiceSample {

    private static String serviceName = "es";
    private static String region = "us-west-1";
    private static String aesEndpoint = ""; // e.g. https://search-mydomain.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com
    private static String index = "my-index";
    private static String type = "_doc";
    private static String id = "1";

    static final AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RestHighLevelClient esClient = esClient(serviceName, region);

        // Create the document as a hash map
        Map<String, Object> document = new HashMap<>();
        document.put("title", "Walk the Line");
        document.put("director", "James Mangold");
        document.put("year", "2005");

        // Form the indexing request, send it, and print the response
        IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(index, type, id).source(document);
        IndexResponse response = esClient.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }

    // Adds the interceptor to the ES REST client
    public static RestHighLevelClient esClient(String serviceName, String region) {
        AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
        signer.setServiceName(serviceName);
        signer.setRegionName(region);
        HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor(serviceName, signer, credentialsProvider);
        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(aesEndpoint)).setHttpClientConfigCallback(hacb -> hacb.addInterceptorLast(interceptor)));
    }
}
```

**Error**
`Cannot resolve AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor`

I have tried multiple maven dependency but still it is not resolved

Could any one please suggest how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class file and place this code. this will do the rest

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.Signer;
import com.amazonaws.http.HttpMethodName;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import static org.apache.http.protocol.HttpCoreContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST;

/**
 * An {@link HttpRequestInterceptor} that signs requests using any AWS {@link Signer}
 * and {@link AWSCredentialsProvider}.
 */
public class AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor {
    /**
     * The service that we're connecting to. Technically not necessary.
     * Could be used by a future Signer, though.
     */
    private final String service;

    /**
     * The particular signer implementation.
     */
    private final Signer signer;

    /**
     * The source of AWS credentials for signing.
     */
    private final AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider;

    /**
     *
     * @param service service that we're connecting to
     * @param signer particular signer implementation
     * @param awsCredentialsProvider source of AWS credentials for signing
     */
    public AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor(final String service,
                                              final Signer signer,
                                              final AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
        this.service = service;
        this.signer = signer;
        this.awsCredentialsProvider = awsCredentialsProvider;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void process(final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context)
            throws HttpException, IOException {
        URIBuilder uriBuilder;
        try {
            uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(request.getRequestLine().getUri());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid URI" , e);
        }

        // Copy Apache HttpRequest to AWS DefaultRequest
        DefaultRequest<?> signableRequest = new DefaultRequest<>(service);

        HttpHost host = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute(HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
        if (host != null) {
            signableRequest.setEndpoint(URI.create(host.toURI()));
        }
        final HttpMethodName httpMethod =
                HttpMethodName.fromValue(request.getRequestLine().getMethod());
        signableRequest.setHttpMethod(httpMethod);
        try {
            signableRequest.setResourcePath(uriBuilder.build().getRawPath());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid URI" , e);
        }

        if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
            HttpEntityEnclosingRequest httpEntityEnclosingRequest =
                    (HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request;
            if (httpEntityEnclosingRequest.getEntity() != null) {
                signableRequest.setContent(httpEntityEnclosingRequest.getEntity().getContent());
            }
        }
        signableRequest.setParameters(nvpToMapParams(uriBuilder.getQueryParams()));
        signableRequest.setHeaders(headerArrayToMap(request.getAllHeaders()));

        // Sign it
        signer.sign(signableRequest, awsCredentialsProvider.getCredentials());

        // Now copy everything back
        request.setHeaders(mapToHeaderArray(signableRequest.getHeaders()));
        if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
            HttpEntityEnclosingRequest httpEntityEnclosingRequest =
                    (HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request;
            if (httpEntityEnclosingRequest.getEntity() != null) {
                BasicHttpEntity basicHttpEntity = new BasicHttpEntity();
                basicHttpEntity.setContent(signableRequest.getContent());
                httpEntityEnclosingRequest.setEntity(basicHttpEntity);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param params list of HTTP query params as NameValuePairs
     * @return a multimap of HTTP query params
     */
    private static Map<String, List<String>> nvpToMapParams(final List<NameValuePair> params) {
        Map<String, List<String>> parameterMap = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        for (NameValuePair nvp : params) {
            List<String> argsList =
                    parameterMap.computeIfAbsent(nvp.getName(), k -> new ArrayList<>());
            argsList.add(nvp.getValue());
        }
        return parameterMap;
    }

    /**
     * @param headers modeled Header objects
     * @return a Map of header entries
     */
    private static Map<String, String> headerArrayToMap(final Header[] headers) {
        Map<String, String> headersMap = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        for (Header header : headers) {
            if (!skipHeader(header)) {
                headersMap.put(header.getName(), header.getValue());
            }
        }
        return headersMap;
    }

    /**
     * @param header header line to check
     * @return true if the given header should be excluded when signing
     */
    private static boolean skipHeader(final Header header) {
        return ("content-length".equalsIgnoreCase(header.getName())
                && "0".equals(header.getValue())) // Strip Content-Length: 0
                || "host".equalsIgnoreCase(header.getName()); // Host comes from endpoint
    }

    /**
     * @param mapHeaders Map of header entries
     * @return modeled Header objects
     */
    private static Header[] mapToHeaderArray(final Map<String, String> mapHeaders) {
        Header[] headers = new Header[mapHeaders.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> headerEntry : mapHeaders.entrySet()) {
            headers[i++] = new BasicHeader(headerEntry.getKey(), headerEntry.getValue());
        }
        return headers;
    }
}
```

This code can be found here: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-opensearch-service-developer-guide/blob/master/sample_code/java/amazon-opensearch-docs-sample-client.zip

Comment: Missing
`import com.amazonaws.DefaultRequest;`

Answer (score 0):

There's [a new maintained fork](https://github.com/acm19/aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor) of the archived aws-request-signing-apache-interceptor. It was upgraded to AWS SDK 2, and has a number of bug fixes, such as supporting retries. Version 2.1.1 was just released to Maven central.